# How to get vim, jsctags, or ctags to treat a .js file as an .html file?

Tags: javascript, vim, macvim, ctags, jsctags

I'm trying to generate tags for a file that ends in .js. This is what happens.

```
Didn't find a name for constructor^@^@node.js:201^@        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick^@              ^^@Error: Didn't find a name for cons
tructor^@    at errorWithCode (/usr/local/lib/cfa2/jscfa.js:157:11)^@    at Array.toType (/usr/local/lib/cfa2/jscfa.js:1574:11)^@    at /usr/local/lib/cfa2/jscfa.js:1994:18^@
at Aval.forEachObj (/usr/local/lib/cfa2/jscfa.js:2020:5)^@    at Aval.toType (/usr/local/lib/cfa2/jscfa.js:1993:8)^@    at funToType (/usr/local/lib/cfa2/jscfa.js:3736:31)^@    a
t getTags (/usr/local/lib/cfa2/jscfa.js:3786:24)^@    at Object.interpret (/usr/local/lib/jsctags/ctags/interp.js:54:21)^@    at Object.scan (/usr/local/lib/jsctags/ctags/index.j
s:104:16)^@    at processPath (/usr/local/bin/jsctags:189:18)^@
```

But if I just rename the file by changing .js to .html, then it works fine.

So something (either vim, ctags, or jsctags) is making some kind of decision based on file extension when generating tags.

What's going on here? Why does changing the filename extension to .html make it work?

Comment: You already have a question open dealing with the exact same issue. You should have added this error message to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know who generated this error message, but, as long as in the question title is stated that you need to make ctags to treat `.js` file as `.html` file, i suggest you to look at the ctags option `--langmap`.

So, you need to pass the following option to ctags: `--langmap=HTML:.js`

But then, of course, all the `.js` files passed to ctags will be treated as HTML files.

More detailed info about ctags options can be found [here](http://goo.gl/gdhvn).